# SQLcl 22.1.1 requires a future Java version?

Tags: sqlcl

I'm a little bit stuck here. It seems the current SQLcl (22.1.1.131.0820 - May 11, 2022) requires a future Java version?

```
C:\Oracle SQLcl\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)
```

So, Java 1.8 (aka JAVA 8) is installed, which seems to be the latest.

```
C:\Oracle SQLcl\bin>sql
This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 11.0.9
```

Where can I get Java version 11.0.9?

Comment: It can be downloaded from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html).  I found it by doing a [Google search for Where can I get Java version 11.0.9](https://www.google.com/search?q=Where+can+I+get+Java+version+11.0.9).

Comment: Indeed, this version works!

Comment: I can see why you might think 8 is the latest - "java.com" offers it for download, and has [a page titled "Why is Java 8 reccommended?"](https://java.com/en/download/why-java-8-recommended.html) which doesn't really give an answer, but "dev.java" offers Java **18**, and has [a whole page on how much better Java has got in later versions](https://dev.java/evolution/). Good to know Oracle are keeping alive Sun's utter inability to manage versioning.

Comment: Thanks, these versions are really confusing, especially because the browser opens a web page suggesting to download version 1.8.0.

Comment: we support 11 AND 17 - 17 is the LTS. 18 is not.

Comment: Java reqs are listed in the release notes https://www.oracle.com/tools/sqlcl/sqlcl-relnotes-22.1.1.html